# python KeyError, can't find error

Tags: python

```
import json
import pandas as pd

data = """
{
    "name": "Wes",
    "place_lived": ["United Stats", "Spain", "Germany"],
    "pet": null,
    "Siblings": [
        {"name": "Scott", "age": 25, "pet": "Zuko"},
        {"name": "Katie", "age": 33, "pet": "Cisco"}]
}
"""

result = json.loads(data)
df = pd.DataFrame(result['siblings'], columns=['name', 'age'])
print(df)
```

I got this example from "Python for Data Analysis" book, and all I got is keyerror, and I don't know where is the error.

Comment: You need to capitalize `'Siblings'`.

Comment: Watch out for case sensitivity! `"Siblings"` is not the same as `"siblings"`

Comment: i'm just being stupid! thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the easiest answer yet. Watch out for case sensitivity.

```
import json
import pandas as pd

data = """
{
    "name": "Wes",
    "place_lived": ["United Stats", "Spain", "Germany"],
    "pet": null,
    "Siblings": [
        {"name": "Scott", "age": 25, "pet": "Zuko"},
        {"name": "Katie", "age": 33, "pet": "Cisco"}]
}
"""

result = json.loads(data)
df = pd.DataFrame(result['Siblings'], columns=['name', 'age'])
print(df)
```